# Jquery each function for outside div

Tags: jquery, function, each

I am trying change divs of outside html. With jquery each function. But my code doesn't work.

It must change spans's html to ExampleDesc1, ExampleDesc2, ExampleDesc3...

```
<div class="example1">
    <a href="#" description"ExampleDesc1"></a>
    <a href="#" description"ExampleDesc2"></a>
    <a href="#" description"ExampleDesc3"></a>
    <a href="#" description"ExampleDesc4"></a>
    <a href="#" description"ExampleDesc5"></a>    
</div>

<div class="example2">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var desc;
    $('.example1 a').each(function () {
        var desc = $(this).attr('description');

        $('.example2 span').each(function () {
            $(this).html(desc);
        });
    });    
</script>
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: description="" ?

Comment: `description="ExampleDesc1"` Your missing an `=` for the `description` attributes, fix that and it will display results. Although you are replacing *all* the children of `example2` each loop.

Comment: use `data-description` if possible aprat from what have been notified in above comments

Comment: Tip: make use of the index part of the each function: `Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )` https://api.jquery.com/each/  `$(".example1 a").each(function(i, e) { `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with adding an `=` between the `description` attribute and value. Rather than an inner loop, just use the index you are on by using `$('.example2 span').eq(i)` when you iterate over `.example1`. Assuming they have the same number of children:

```js
$('.example1 a').each(function (i) {
    var desc = $(this).attr('description');
    $('.example2 span').eq(i).html(desc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example1">
    <a href="#" description="ExampleDesc1"></a>
    <a href="#" description="ExampleDesc2"></a>
    <a href="#" description="ExampleDesc3"></a>
    <a href="#" description="ExampleDesc4"></a>
    <a href="#" description="ExampleDesc5"></a>    
</div>

<div class="example2">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner loop (`$('.example2 span').each`) executes once every iteration of the outer loop (`$('.example1 a').each`). So the content of `<span>`'s will always be the description of the last `<a>`.

In order to to what you are trying to do, you should assign a different ID to each span.